# Не работает выход из программы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я разрабатывал программу-прототип чата двух людей. Я хочу настроить выход из него, но ничего не получается. Прошу помочь, потому что только учусь

```
import sys

def callNickname():
    nickUser=input("Enter your nickname for User --> ")
    return nickUser
def answerUser(nickUser):
    answerUser=input("@"+nickUser+"--> ")
    return ("@"+nickUser+"-->"+answerUser+"\n")


userFile=open('FilesChat\log.txt','w')
userNick_0= callNickname()
userNick_1= callNickname()
user_0="NULL"
user_1="NULL"

while user_0  not in ['quit', 'exit', 'konec']:
    user_0=answerUser(userNick_0)
    user_1=answerUser(userNick_1)
    userFile.write(user_0)
    userFile.write(user_1)
userFile.close()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Функция `answerUser` возвращает строку, которая никогда не может совпасть с одной из списка: `['quit', 'exit', 'konec']`

Comment: я хочу добавить досрочное завершение программы из-за прерывания цикла While после ввода exit,quit,konec.Не подскажете ли как реализовать, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы сравнивать со списком

```
['quit', 'exit', 'konec']
```

вам нужны некоторые преобразования

```
user_0 = user_0.strip().split('>')[1]             # !!!
```

---

```
import sys

def callNickname():
    nickUser = input("Enter your nickname for User --> ")
    return nickUser
    
def answerUser(nickUser):
    answerUser = input("@"+nickUser+"--> ")
    return ("@"+nickUser+"-->"+answerUser+"\n")


userFile = open('FilesChat\log.txt','w')                  
userNick_0 = callNickname()
userNick_1 = callNickname()

user_0 = None
user_1 = None

while not user_0 in ['quit', 'exit', 'konec']:
    user_0 = answerUser(userNick_0)
    user_1 = answerUser(userNick_1)
    userFile.write(user_0)
    userFile.write(user_1)
    
    user_0 = user_0.strip().split('>')[1]             # !!!
    
    
userFile.close()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое